# Installing DVDVideoSoft Without Additional Add-Ons?

Tags: windows-7

I wish to upgrade my current version of [DVDVideoSoft](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/) to the latest version. Having downloaded & clicked the installer file I am confronted with the following dialogue box which concerns me & have at present cancelled the installation:

[image]

I do not wish additional baggage to be installed alongside the Application (and would under normal circumstances choose the **Custom installation (Advanced)** option).

From what I can see (unless i'm reading it incorrectly) even that option does not allow me to prevent **Search Protect** or **Conduit Search** from being installed on my PC.

If this is indeed the case:

- Is there a way around this problem, to install [DVDVideoSoft](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/) on its own ?
- What are my other options (if the above isn't possible) ?

Comment: If you were to select "Custom Installation" nothing except the program you wanted to install would be selected using those exact settings.  The fact is Conduit Search is some very nasty software, why support any software, that even offers to install it?

Comment: @Ramhound I totally agree with your second sentence (but am unsure of the alternative(s)). With respect to your 1st sentence in terms of Custom installation, which boxes would be appropriate to tick ?

Comment: Select **None** of them if you want nothing else installed?

Comment: @Ramhound Is it possible to select None ?

Comment: @Ramhound You are correct, I selected Custom install (advanced) & then deselected the two corresponding boxes. I didn't know that that was possible, I thought when you choose the custom install at least one corresponding box would have to be ticked, which isn't the case. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

> By clicking "Next" **and choosing to install Search Protect** ...

If you don't choose to install it, it won't install.

Comment: See comments section above